# Sqoop Import - What does directory structure _temporary/1 , _temporary/2 etc mean?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop2, sqoop

I had started a sqoop import which has been going on for more than 10 days and is still running.

When I did:

```
hadoop fs -du -h <base-directory>/*/
```

Got this:

```
2.6 TB    <base-directory>/_temporary/1
502.6 GB  <base-directory>/_temporary/2
3.5 TB    <base-directory>/_temporary/3
```

What does this directory structure mean? Has it failed twice and is retrying third time?